# Can I use custom HttpClient in apache httpcomponent fluent-hc?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request use default httpClient in Executor, but I want to add retry handle when http request failed for some exception.

How can I do it?

I have used this function to send request:

```
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance(httpClient);
executor.execute(Request.Get("Url"));
```

Comment: how are you creating `httpclient`? Perhaps you attach a custom `ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy` to `httpclient` when you create it?

Comment: Of course, you can. Why are you not sure?